# How to send data from a C# MVC ASP.net Application to a C# WPF Application

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, wpf

I am wondering how I can send information from a **C# MVC Web Application** to a **C# Desktop Application**.

For example, I want to be able to send some `string`s from my web application that is hosted on some server to a client's personal computer where they will have my desktop application executable somewhere on their local machine. Also, I am trying to *avoid* the client having to open the desktop application (that will be running in the background) to click anything. I am wanting the desktop application to constantly be checking for data coming in from the web application. I would probably have a `while()` loop checking for that information in the desktop application and then once it has received data from the web application I will do stuff with it on the desktop side.

Can anyone point me to some good examples of this or provide a **simple** example of this being done with some `string`s?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When thinking about this [SignalR](https://www.asp.net/signalr) comes to mind, or perhaps implement in the MVC application a web hook and consume it in the WPF application.

A good starting point for Signalr you can find [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/getting-started/tutorial-getting-started-with-signalr-and-mvc).

Comment: For anyone who cares, this is the correct answer but it won't let me up vote it because I mistakenly down-voted it. Also I found this https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/804770/Implementing-SignalR-in-Desktop-Applications

Comment: And - https://www.codeguru.com/columns/experts/how-to-push-data-from-server-to-client-using-signalr.htm